# GPX-Tracks are not displayed correctly by many applications/web applications

Tags: qgis, gps, gpx

I have a problem regarding GPX tracks that were created from Shapefiles using QGIS.

The shapefiles were created by selecting all parts of a route from a PostGIS database.
The polylines were merged with QGIS and then exported as a GPX file by using the 'Save as' option.

The resulting GPX files look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="GDAL 1.11.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ogr="http://osgeo.org/gdal" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
<metadata><bounds minlat="51.533449555703989" minlon="6.983701320292362" maxlat="51.554475633460669" maxlon="7.010408625662222"/></metadata>

<trk>
<extensions>
<ogr:OBJECTID>31751.0</ogr:OBJECTID>
</extensions>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="51.54792023947288" lon="6.986589223144231">
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="51.547997675144856" lon="6.986820893755352">
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="51.548138136988818" lon="6.986910766789045">
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="51.548352505219341" lon="6.987013118209317">
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="51.549051234512156" lon="6.987331861261017">
</trkpt>
</trkseg>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="51.54792023947288" lon="6.986589223144231">
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="51.547840418735099" lon="6.986046522387352">
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="51.547799254904852" lon="6.985851100932796">
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="51.547750380482739" lon="6.985724171010038">
</trkpt>
```

And so on. There are 8 segments of the track in total.

The issue is that while some web applications are able to display this track without a problem (like http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/)

[image: Displayed using GPS Visualizer]

many others are not (http://www.maplorer.com/view_gpx.html ) [image: Displayed using maplorer]

I have already tried adding timestamps to the points, but that didn't change anything.

I assume that the issue has something to do with the segments because if I merge all segments of the track using the GPX_Editor from Sourceforge the route gets distorted exactly like it does in the maplorer example. 
No matter what application i use, the track is either displayed correctly as in the first example or falsely like in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that false displaying applications don't respect `<trkseg>` correctly.

If you add `</trk><trk>` to every trkseg change, it might come out correct.

Otherwise you have to create a new GPX file for every `<trkseg>` using one trkseg per track and file.